# jQuery :first selector issue

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-selectors

I've got the following HTML, and I'm trying to target the first < p >

```
<div id="div-1">
    <h2>Foo</h2>
    <p>Bar</p>
    <p><iframe></p>
</div>
```

I tried using the following jQuery:

```
$("div#div-1 p:first").css('color','red');
```

It didn't work, so I thought it was the iframe that was causing the issue, but then I tried inserting something else into the < p >, and it still didn't work:

```
<div id="div-1">
    <h2>Foo</h2>
    <p>Bar</p>
    <p><h3>Foobar</h3></p>
</div>
```

So obviously it's an issue with nesting elements within a < p >. 
How do I resolve this? Due to using Wordpress, I'm kind of stuck with using an iFrame nested inside a < p >, so I need to work around that.

Comment: But it works: http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/Xn4uX/

Comment: Your HTML is broken. You never close your `<iframe>` tag.

Comment: What on earth does "it didn't work" mean? Why do people think that this is an acceptable error description?

Comment: @Tomalak, "$("div#div-1 p:first").css('color','red');
Did not color the first paragraph red as I expected." should be a perfectly valid description of a problem.

Comment: Because the jQuery code clearly was meant to change the paragraph's color to red... If it didn't work, then guess what it didn't do..

Comment: @Captain: Correct. Why is that not in the question?

Comment: @Ian: We shouldn't have to guess. If you're explicit about what _is_ and _is not_ happening, then our answers can be terse and explicit. This includes finding out what the exact state of the element becomes, and whether there are any Firebug errors, etc. Otherwise they contain a large margin of error where we just have to assume what you mean and what you have observed.

Comment: @Tomalak: Fair enough. I figured there was only one unfavorable state possible when trying to change an element's color to red. I will lower my assumption hurdle accordingly.

Comment: @Ian: It's likely not the case here, but when a poster makes assumptions about limiting the information they provide in a question, nine times out of ten the information that solves the problem is in the missed-out part. :) After all, if you knew enough to make those assumptions in the first place, you probably wouldn't be having the problem!

Comment: @Tomalak: Gotcha, just like when my car doesn't start, I can't assume that it's broken! :)

Comment: @Ian: More like "my car won't work"; is it broken, or did you just forget to put petrol in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/EFjsZ/1/

But you should really end the `<iframe>` tag...

Answer (score -1):

$div = $("div-1");
var obj = $div.find("p:first");